# What is the difference between call() and __call__() method in python?

Tags: python, class, tensorflow, methods

In the tensorflow documentation I see the call() method defined when subclassing activations and models. However, in case of subclassing regularizers, initializers and constraints, they define the __class__() method instead.

When playing around with both, I could not find any differences myself.

Could someone tell me what the difference is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`call()` is just a regular method that you can call on an instance of a class, e.g. `foo.call(...)`.

`__call__()` is a special method that makes the instance itself callable. So instead of doing `foo.call(...)` you can just do `foo(...)`. (You can also do `foo.__call__()` still.)

Answer (score 5):

`__call__` is a python magic method (or dunder method) that makes class objects callable. but on the other hand `call` is a user-defined method in Keras which in the background uses mentioned `__call__` method but before using it this user-defined `call` does some extra things like building weight and bias tensors based on the input tensor shape.